# SQL to sum values after you queried them

Tags: postgresql

sorry for that bad title.
I have a postgreSQL database with some columns one of them is k_time (some epoch stuff) and to even display some readable results I need to run a query that converts this k_time to timestamp and select a specific date.

this is the query, for security reasons I overwrote the other column names, should not be relevant

```
select
to_timestamp(k_time/1000),
k_time,
k_123,
k_456,
SUM(789)  as 789,
SUM(111)  as 111,
SUM(aaa)  as aaa
FROM table
WHERE k_abc = 0
AND to_timestamp(k_time/1000) BETWEEN '2015-11-22'::DATE AND '2015-11-24'::DATE
AND k_xyz = 'test' AND k_456 = 'result'

GROUP BY k_time,k_123,k_456
ORDER BY k_time,k_123,k_456;
```

this query results in

how the heck can I put a table inside here? lol :-/ cannot show you my result
It comes from Postico

EDIT:
sorry guys I could not find the time to update this properly with the actual table contents I have.
My Point basically is after I run that query I have a column of to_timestamp where every hour of that day is one row (that is because the sql table aggregates it like that)

---

```
2015-11-23 00:00:00+00  1448236800000   K_456   k_xyz   0   4   84
2015-11-23 00:00:00+00  1448236800000   K_457   k_xyz   0   0   2
2015-11-23 00:00:00+00  1448236800000   K_458   k_xyz   0   15  263
2015-11-23 00:00:00+00  1448236800000   K_459   k_xyz   0   0   3
2015-11-23 00:00:00+00  1448236800000   K_460   k_xyz   0   1   191
2015-11-23 00:01:00+00  1448244000000   K_456   k_xyz   0   2   260
2015-11-23 00:01:00+00  1448244000000   K_457   k_xyz   0   1   63
```

finally the query result
What I need from that:
A single row for this whole day containting the sum of all of the values in the last three columns

Comment: Use the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) data sample and post here what would be your desired result FROM that data sample. Add here the generated link.

Comment: It is better to remove altogether irrelevant columns from your query. And it is more useful to see source data than the query result.

Comment: see my last edit please :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to fit the value in k_time inbetween two dates, you probably need to drop "/1000" in your sql.

Here:

```
select
to_timestamp(k_time),
k_time,
k_123,
k_456,
SUM(789)  as 789,
SUM(111)  as 111,
SUM(aaa)  as aaa
FROM table
WHERE k_abc = 0
AND to_timestamp(k_time) BETWEEN '2015-11-22'::DATE AND '2015-11-24'::DATE
AND k_xyz = 'test' AND k_456 = 'result'
GROUP BY k_time,k_123,k_456
ORDER BY k_time,k_123,k_456;
```

What I said depends on whether the values in "k_time" are stored as seconds or milliseconds.

- if values in "k_time" are seconds, then drop "/1000"
- if values in "k_time" are milliseconds, then keep "/1000"

Example: date "2015-11-12 14:10:51" translates to "1447330251" in seconds and "1447330251000" in milliseconds.